# SwiftUI on button tap call MKMapView.setRegion

Tags: swiftui

In a `NavigationView` I have a `Button` and a `MKMapView` (called `MapView`). When the user taps the button the map should zoom to the user's location.

I know how to make use of `MKMapView.setRegion` to zoom to the users's location, but I can't figure out how the correct way to make `MapView` aware that it should perform this action when the user taps the button.

If I somehow have a reference to my `MapView` object, I can call `setRegion`, but I realize that is imperative and now when I'm learning SwiftUI I try to think declaratively instead.

So I believe I should set a `State` variable of some type and make `MapView` listen to changes to that variable. But if I manage to do that, then `MapView` calling `setRegion` would be imperative anyway.

So I'm scratching my head here. What should I do?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var foo: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView()
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    HStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            // zoom to user's location
                            self.foo.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "location")
                        }
                })
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var foo: Bool

    // if foo is changed, then call zoomToUserLocation()

    func zoomToUserLocation() {
        // ...
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where do you get `region` (or it is set), but on any such binding changed the `updateUIView` of representable is called, so would do the call there and make it asynchronous, like below

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    // if needed make something conditional here on `foo`

    self.zoomToUserLocation()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `updateUIView` method of UIViewRepresentable. I would it use like this:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var foo: Bool

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

        if foo {
            self.zoomToUserLocation()
        }

    }

    func zoomToUserLocation() {
        // ...
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

You can also make something conditional like Asperi said.